# Active Record Does Not Set Foreign Key With has_many and belongs_to does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Background - I have 2 models, a upload model and a user model. Originally I had owner_id in the upload model(table) as the foreign key for the  id of the user in the user model. However I could not get the foreign key to work, so I decided to go the "rails " way by renaming owner_id to user_id. Even after setting the column to user_id, it does not populate with any values at all.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :uploads
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

Have tried explicitly setting the key, but it still does not populate the user_id field in the uploads table

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :uploads ,:foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

Might be something simple but I cant seem to find what it is. any suggestions ?

** the upload controller

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController


  def index

   @uploads = Upload.all 

  end

  def new
   @upload = Upload.new
  end

 def create
  @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
    if @upload.save
        flash[:notice] = "your file has been uploaded"
        redirect_to uploads_path

    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
 end

 def destroy
  @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  @upload.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Sucessfully deleted your file"
  redirect_to uploads_path
 end


 def download
    upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
    #location = "#{Rails.root}" 

   # send_file  (@upload)
#send_file('public/test_file.pdf', :filename => 'Test File', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'attachment', :streaming => 'true', :buffer_size => '4096')
    send_file  upload.uploaded.path,
        :filename => upload.uploaded_file_name,
                :type => upload.uploaded_content_type,
        :disposition => 'attachment'
    flash[:notice] = "Your file has been downloaded"
 end


end
```

**The upload form

```
<%= form_for(@upload, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |form| %>
 <form>
<fieldset>
<div class="clearfix">
         <label for="fileInput">File input</label>
 <div class="input">
          <%= form.file_field :uploaded %>
</div>


 <div class="actions">
           <input type="submit" class="btn primary" <%= form.submit "Upload" %> &nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
          </div>


</fieldset>
</form>
<% end %>
```

== Schema Information

Table name: users

id                     :integer         not null, primary key

email                  :string(255)     default(""), not null

encrypted_password     :string(128)     default(""), not null

reset_password_token   :string(255)

reset_password_sent_at :datetime

remember_created_at    :datetime

sign_in_count          :integer         default(0)

current_sign_in_at     :datetime

last_sign_in_at        :datetime

current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)**

last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)

created_at             :datetime

updated_at             :datetime

admin                  :boolean         default(FALSE)

== Schema Information -----------------------------------------

Table name: uploads

id                    :integer

created_at            :datetime

updated_at            :datetime

uploaded_file_name    :string(255)

uploaded_content_type :string(255)

uploaded_file_size    :integer

uploaded_updated_at   :datetime

user_id               :integer

Comment: Also post here both the User model and the Upload Model.

Comment: I think the problem is on the form or controller, please paste both.

Comment: Updated my question with the info.

Comment: Got it, it was in my controller, the way I was creating an upload. I have post the correction below. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.   `def create
  @upload = current_user.uploads.create(params[:upload])
        if @upload.save
                flash[:notice] = "your file has been uploaded"
                redirect_to uploads_path

        else
                render :action => 'new'
        end
 end
`  Please check the controller and form for any additional errors

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :uploads ,:foreign_key => 'users_id'
end
```

the `users_id` should be `user_id`.

Comment: Sorry , i made a typo when I was posting the message. I did use `user_id` Have corrected my post and included the complete model. Do you think my controllers will have anything to do with the user_id not been saved even though the relationship is explicitly there ?